# Efficient algorithm to index fuzzy hash signatures

Tags: algorithm, hash, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I need to find if the new fuzzy hash signature I obtain is similar (to an stablished degree of certainty) to the others signatures I have obtained.

Problem is, there's no way to sort fuzzy hash, so rather than use brute force and compare them all, I'd like to know if there is a good algorithm to index fuzzy signatures.

Comment: define: fuzzy hash signature

Comment: the signature, digest or hash, is the result of applying the hash algorithm, in this case a fuzzy hash. (sorry if my english is not very good)